# FTP access from Python (or command line) not working, only from FileZilla

Tags: python, ip, google-colaboratory, ftplib

A public data server from Brazil's government (ftp://ftp.mtps.gov.br) changed recently its configurations and it's not accessible from a browser anymore. We get a blank page.

On ftplib, it times out without detailing. On wget, on command line, this is what it says:

[image: wget attempt at downloading the data]

On FileZilla, access is immediate.

[image: filezilla result]

What can be happening and how could I go around that problem?

EDIT: I figured why it times out. Brazilian government has blocked that FTP address to foreign IPs. Since I am accessing the FTP over Google Colaboratory, it thinks I'm out of Brazil and times me out. How can I programmatically inform a Brazilian IP in order to connect?

Comment: You didn't describe any actual problem with Python. Asking why wget does not work, when FileZilla does, is not a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I'm looking for a programming solution, in fact, for a non-programming problem. But the same problem happened when I used ftplib, even if the error message was not as detailed.

Comment: That does not make it a programming question. Once you make the connection working using an FTP client, and ftplib still won't be working, then you will have a programming question. Until then, please ask your problem with the FTP client at an appropriate site, like [su].